# How to define the name of a radio button and get its checked value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am trying to get the value of a radio button as JSON. This is my code:

```
for (const o of i.options){

        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        x.setAttribute("id", "radioID");
        x.name = RadioBtn;

        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode(o);
        y.appendChild(t);

        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.height = "5px";
        div.appendChild(x);
        div.appendChild(y);
        document.getElementById("radioButton").appendChild(div);


        window.data.appendChild(x);
        window.data.appendChild(y);
        window.data.appendChild(div);
      }


const fifthQuestion = JSON.stringify($("input[name=RadioBtn]:checked").val());
console.log(fifthQuestion);
```

I get the following errors:

```
1. ReferenceError: RadioBtn is not defined
2. ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I seem not to be defining the name of the radio button the right way. How can I do that and get the input of the checked radio button?

Comment: #1) Did you forget the quotes around that value?  It's trying to use it as a variable without the quotes.  #2) You didn't include jquery on your page, or it is running in noConflict mode and is not bound to `$`

Comment: `$ is not defined` is because you tried to use jQuery syntax but you didn't load jQuery into your page. But the rest of the time you aren't using jQuery for anything, so maybe you don't really want jQuery? You can use `document.querySelector()` instead of that. Also it's unclear why you'd need to run `JSON.stringify` on the value of a button - I guess the value really is just a simple ID or something? I didn't see anywhere that you actually set a value for the radio button.

Comment: And yeah I'd assume `x.name = RadioBtn;` was supposed to be `x.name = 'RadioBtn';`

Comment: @Taplar Fixed the first issue by adding the quotes, thanks :) I am still getting the same error though. I am using `Node.js` and I have ran `"npm install jQuery"`. Did I miss to install something?

Comment: `npm install jQuery` is just going to download that repository to your node_modules.  It's not going to be automatically included on things.

Comment: @ADyson How can I use `document.querySelector()`? I tried it and I couldn't get it to work. I am trying to get the input as JSON in order to make it downloadable by the person who answered the question as a JSON.  I am getting the `const o of i.options` from a JSON file as well.

Comment: @Taplar I see. I used those commands `const { JSDOM } = require( "jsdom" );
const { window } = new JSDOM( "" );
const $ = require( "jquery" )( window );` from https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery However, its giving me a different error now `SyntaxError: Identifier 'window' has already been declared`

Comment: So you mean the answer to one of the questions is some JSON? But a radio button is multiple choice...you don't need to have the actual JSON as the answer value, you just need an ID which represents the correct answer from the selection. (And the fact that `i.options` was originally taken from some JSON data has no relevance to any of this.)

Comment: `document.querySelector("input[name=RadioBtn]:checked")` would select the clicked radio button. Then you'd use `.value` to get its value - but like I said before, you haven't actually assigned any value to the radio button when you created it, as far as I can see. P.S. Stop messing around with jQuery installs, you don't need it.

Comment: @ADyson I understand what you mean. I will try assigning a value to each button. `const fifthQuestion = JSON.stringify(document.querySelector("input[name=RadioBtn]:checked").value);` worked for me.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you :) Got it working with `x.value = o;` , `o` was the text from the JSON file.